# Краш при вызове toast

Tags: java, android

Имеются 2 activity mainactivity и register. по нажатию кнопки вызывается toast, но приложение падает, ошибок никаких не выдаёт в консолях.

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(register.this, "11", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Что я делаю не так?

Полный код:

```
public void onClick(View view) throws MalformedURLException {
    EditText nickname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    if (nickname.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder1.setMessage("The login field should not be empty");
        builder1.setCancelable(true);

        builder1.setPositiveButton(
                "Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
        alert11.show();
    }
    else
    {
        String hash = md5(nickname.getText().toString());
        // Generate key pair for 4096-bit RSA encryption and decryption
        Key publicKey = null;
        Key privateKey = null;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            kpg.initialize(4096);
            KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
            publicKey = kp.getPublic();
            privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
            System.out.println("public: \n");
            System.out.println(publicKey.toString());
            System.out.println("private: \n");
            System.out.println(privateKey.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Crypto", "RSA key pair error");
        }

        SaveKey(publicKey, hash + "_public_key");
        SaveKey(privateKey, hash + "_private_key");

        int i=0;

        //String myURL = "http://s92640jz.bget.ru/register.php";
        //String parammetrs = "login=22&open_key=XXX&key_size=4096";

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("login", nickname.getText().toString())
                .add("open_key", "XXX")
                .add("key_size", "4096")
                .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://s92640jz.bget.ru/register.php")
                .post(formBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request)
                .enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(final Call call, IOException e) {
                        // Error
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // For the example, you can show an error dialog or a toast
                                // on the main UI thread
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                        String res = response.body().string();

                        try{
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(res);
                            String answer = jsonObject.getString("r_1");
                            Log.d("TAG", "response is: " + answer);


                        } catch (JSONException e){}
                        try{
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(res);
                            String answer = jsonObject.getString("r_0");
                            Log.d("TAG", "response is: " + answer);
                        } catch (JSONException e){}

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(register.this, "11", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        //toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();
                        // Do something with the response
                    }
                });

    }
```

Comment: покажите код обработки нажатия кнопки..

Comment: Я не верю вам, что в консоли нет ошибок.

Comment: Добавил в первый пост

Comment: Метод onResponse не имеет доступа к UI потоку, вызывайте Toast извне или при помощи Runnable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onResponce вызывается не в UI потоке. Toast можно показывать (как и вообще манипулировать с разметкой) можно только в UI потоке. Т.е. вам надо окружить этот код в

```
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //это будет вызвано в UI потоке. Тут можно показать Toast
        }
    });
```